# Getting powerbi to function like powerpivot does

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot

I am trying to get a chart in powerbi to function like when I had previously built a chart in powerpivot.

Where it IS similar is that when I have a date field that is in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and I drag that into my chart it auto-converts/expresses the date into a year, month and day field individually. What I can then do however in PowerPivot that I can't seem to figure out in bi is the ability to then drag the year and month separately to the axis section and thus the axis shows all months grouped into the years. BI seems to want to only show the months and the data is grouped year by year or just by the year itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a Date field in (e.g. to the Axis well of a Line Chart) then it will generate the default "Date Hierarchy" : Year / Quarter / Month / Day.  You can delete levels you don't want (e.g. Quarter, Day).

With that set up how you want, look in the top left of the chart visual's frame for 3 buttons.  The one you likely want is the 3rd - **Expand all down one level in the hierarchy**.

Note the exact results vary a bit for some visuals.